'T' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0
I'm working on a Blazor-Server project with an Udemy course. We started with ABP framework. So i didn't code any controllers.
I have 2 GetPagedListAsync methods, one without **includeProperties **and one with **includeProperties **like this;
*the one without;
*
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetPagedListAsync<TKey>(int skipCount, int maxResultCount, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? predicate = null, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>>? orderBy = null)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = await WithDetailsAsync();

    if (predicate != null)
        queryable = queryable.Where(predicate);

    if (orderBy != null)
        queryable.OrderBy(orderBy);

    return await queryable.Skip(skipCount).Take(maxResultCount).ToListAsync();
}

*the one with;
*
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetPagedLastListAsync<TKey>(int skipCount, int maxResultCount, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? predicate = null, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>>? orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = await WithDetailsAsync(includeProperties);

    if (predicate != null)
        queryable = queryable.Where(predicate);

    if (orderBy != null)
        queryable.OrderByDescending(orderBy);

    return await queryable.Skip(skipCount).Take(maxResultCount).ToListAsync();
}

when i use it like this, I have no problems about it;
await _bankaRepository.GetPagedLastListAsync(input.SkipCount, input.MaxResultCount, b => b.Durum == input.Durum, b => b.Kod);

but when i use it like this, im getting a 500 error.
await _bankaRepository.GetPagedLastListAsync(input.SkipCount, input.MaxResultCount, b => b.Durum == input.Durum, b => b.Kod, b => b.OzelKod1, b => b.OzelKod2);

And when i try to catch that error, this is the only thing that i can see;
'T' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
Instructor is working on .NET 6, im working on .NET 8. Im not sure what is the reason for that error but i just wanted to tell it.
Also i want to share the entites
public class Banka : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public string Kod { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Ad { get; set; } = null!;
    public Guid? OzelKod1ID { get; set; }
    public Guid? OzelKod2ID { get; set; }
    public string? Aciklama { get; set; }
    public bool Durum { get; set; }

    public OzelKod? OzelKod1 { get; set; } 
    public OzelKod? OzelKod2 { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<BankaSube>? BankaSubeler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MakbuzHareket>? MakbuzHareketler { get; set; }
}

public class OzelKod : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public string? Kod { get; set; }
    public string? Ad { get; set; }
    public OzelKodTuru KodTuru { get; set; }
    public KartTuru KartTuru { get; set; }
    public string? Aciklama { get; set; }
    public bool Durum { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BankaHesap>? OzelKod1BankaHesaplar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BankaHesap>? OzelKod2BankaHesaplar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Banka>? OzelKod1Bankalar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Banka>? OzelKod2Bankalar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BankaSube>? OzelKod1BankaSubeler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BankaSube>? OzelKod2BankaSubeler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Birim>? OzelKod1Birimler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Birim>? OzelKod2Birimler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cari>? OzelKod1Cariler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cari>? OzelKod2Cariler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Depo>? OzelKod1Depolar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Depo>? OzelKod2Depolar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fatura>? OzelKod1Faturalar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Fatura>? OzelKod2Faturalar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Hizmet>? OzelKod1Hizmetler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Hizmet>? OzelKod2Hizmetler { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Kasa>? OzelKod1Kasalar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Kasa>? OzelKod2Kasalar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Makbuz>? OzelKod1Makbuzlar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Makbuz>? OzelKod2Makbuzlar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Masraf>? OzelKod1Masraflar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Masraf>? OzelKod2Masraflar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Stok>? OzelKod1Stoklar { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Stok>? OzelKod2Stoklar { get; set; }
}

and i have a map like this
CreateMap<Banka, ListBankaDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.OzelKod1Adi, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.OzelKod1.Ad))
    .ForMember(x => x.OzelKod2Adi, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.OzelKod2.Ad));   

I did all the same things with the instructor. So i can not detect what the real problem is. I'm waiting for a help from you guys. Thank you in advance.
